# Does a Java try catch use a closure to catch terminating child threads while the parent thread is blocked?

Tags: java, timeout, closures, threadpoolexecutor, cancellation

I am looking for an expansion of the question asked here: [Does a Future timeout kill the Thread execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231508/does-a-future-timeout-kill-the-thread-execution)

Given the following code snippet, I am curious to know if the catch for TimeoutException will catch threads that exceed the timelimit in some kind of closure? Will these catch even when the main thread is being blocked by awaitTermination()? This implementation seems to work. ...but it may be that I have simply been lucky so far to have no deadlocks and no apparent race conditions.

```
public List<T> setupThreads() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    if (nThreads < 1 || timeout < 1 || preRunObjects == null || preRunObjects.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    List<T> postRunObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Future<T>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);
    for (T runMe : preRunObjects) {
        futures.add(executor.submit(runMe));
    }
    for (Future<T> f : futures) {
        try {
            postRunObjects.add(f.get(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        } catch (TimeoutException te) {
            log.warn("A thread has failed to run in time! It will be canceled.");
            if(!f.isDone()) {
                f.cancel(true);
                if(f.isCancelled()) {
                    log.info("Punishment complete!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    executor.awaitTermination((timeout * postRunObjects.size()), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return postRunObjects;
}
```

Comment: Since Java didn't have closures until Java 7, and has had exceptions since day 1 I *think* the answer is no.

Comment: The main thread will block on `f.get`, `awaitTermination` will only run when all the future have either timed out or completed.

Comment: james large and BevynQ have the right answer to the question. That is to say that the very question is broken. I missed the part about future.get() blocking in the docs. Thus, by the time awaitTermination() is run, I have already run and completed every child thread, and all threads are in a state that would not cause awaitTermination() to block. This would render it pointless in the code snippet. However, I now have a more complete picture.
Thank you Elliott Frisch, I actually have never attempted to use closures in 6 and now I am glad that I didn't/won't try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am curious to know if the catch for TimeoutException will catch threads that exceed the timelimit in some kind of closure? Will these catch even when the main thread is being blocked by awaitTermination()?

In some kind of closure?  Would it matter?

Your main thread does not call `executor.awaitTermination()` until *after* the `for(...)` loop has completed.

Also note:  All of the `f.get()` calls are sequential:  Your main thread will wait up to `timeout` seconds for the first result, and then it will wait up to `timeout` *more* seconds for the next result, ...and the next, ...and the next, ...and so on.

Is that what you had in mind?  Or did you mean to wait no longer than `timeout` *total* seconds?